# My husbands name is on patent.He passed away.Who is legal owner now?

Tags: ownership

My husband developed patent # us496567..He passed away. Another company is using the procedure..Who owns the rights?

Comment: Did you perhaps leave a digit off the patent number? If so please correct it.

Comment: Can you please check the patent number and perhaps provide us you husband's name. I didn't find a single US patent with "Lobdon" as the inventor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for your loss.

A patent has one or several inventors and one or several owners. Those do not have to overlap. The inventors stay the same, the owners can change as a patent can be treated as normal property and therefore sold.

US496567 is an old patent, it has lapsed (patents only protect an invention for a certain time, 20 years now, at that time it was less), so nobody owns it anymore.

This patent is from 1893, are you sure it is the right one?